# create quantile category variables using defined cut-points in Stata

Tags: categories, stata, quantile

I am trying to create indicator variables using different quantile levels. I am creating a  variable that contains categories corresponding to quantiles. For one variable, the code I am using is

```
xtile PH_scale = PH, nq(4)
tab PH_scale, gen(PH_scale_)
```

Also, I know that if I want to use my own cutpoints instead of the default  (e.g., `nq(4)`) I can define my own cut-points by using

```
input class
xtile PH_scale = PH, cutpoint(class)
```

But there are several variables for which I want to define the cut-points differently.

Normally, cut-points work as:

```
(−∞, x[25] ], (x[25], x[50] ], (x[50], x[75] ], (x[75], +∞)
where x[25], x[50], and x[75] are, respectively, the 25th, 50th (median), and 75th percentiles
```

and Stata will automatically assign numbers to each of those intervals (e.g., 1 to  (−∞, x[25] ], 2 to (x[25], x[50] ], and so on)

However, what I want is

```
 Assign category 1 to values located in (−∞, x[25] ] AND (x[75], +∞)
 Assign category 2 to values located in (x[25], x[50] ] AND (x[50], x[75] ]
```

I hope I explain my problem clearly enough. I am not sure whether I can do this using the `xtile` command. Any other methods that can solve this problem are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
xtile PH_scale = PH, nq(4)
```

this is a easy `replace`

```
replace PH_scale = cond(inlist(PH_scale, 1, 4), 1, 2)
```

Alternatively, create percentiles directly

```
_pctile PH, nq(4) 
gen PH_scale = cond(PH < r(r1) | PH > r(r3), 1, 2) if PH < .
```

Note that indicator variables are widely defined as those with values 1 and 0, but the principles are the same either way.